# Deathbrand Armor with quest completed under Level 36?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Is it possible to get the full set of Deathbrand Armour below level 36, or after level 36 if I've already completed the quest?

I completed the [Deathbrand Quest](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Deathbrand_(Quest)) under level 36 by using the Wax Key perk at Gyldenhul Barrow.

The Deathbrand Helm chest spawned after I completed the quest. The Deathbrand Armor (chest piece) chest has not spawned.

Is there's a way to trigger the remaining armour pieces chests to spawn now? Will they spawn eventually when I hit level 36?

Comment: Umm, seems you didn't got how long this quest is. You need to get to 4 chests and then to ruins. It's not a level issue.

Comment: @Mithoron umm, seems you didn't read the question. The chests didn't spawn.

Comment: Then you didn't *complete* it. You can't do it below 36 level.

Comment: @Mithoron ummm, you absolutely can. Perhaps reading the question would clear up any misunderstanding you might have.